# Login & Extract Data from a webpage Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, html, extract

So i am trying this to logon to a website and then get the element off the other webpages within the website "http://www.website.com"

```
public class TicketingJsoup {

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException{
       try {
            String url = "www.website.com";
            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

            response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .data("Action", "Login")
                    .data("User", "myuser")
                    .data("Password", "mypass")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .execute();

            Document document = response.parse();
            System.out.println(document);

            Map<String, String> loginCookies = response.cookies();


               Elements ticketNumber = doc.select("body > div.MainBox.ARIARoleMain.UseArticleColors > div.Headline > h1");
              System.out.println(ticketNumber);   
              System.out.println("TEST");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

Stack trace

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:516)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:534)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
at TicketingJsoup.main(TicketingJsoup.java:25)
```

What am i doing wrong? I'm racking my brain trying to figure out how to do this, ive also tried many other things but they lead to a dead end. I think this is the best way but if i am mistake please show me a better way.

Thanks.

Comment: Header traces you posted are POST request.  Login failed?  Or the next GET request failed?

Comment: Post the HTTP trace.

Comment: I am so sorry i have never done a HTTP trace i have tried to use the function public HttpTrace() from the Apache library but it keeps telling me to create the class could you please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
   try {
        String url = "www.website.com";
        Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

        response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .data("Action", "Login")
                .data("User", "your_login")
                .data("Password", "your_password")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .execute();

        Document document = response.parse();
        System.out.println(document);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: omfg you did it you requested the page i wanted how what did i do wrong thankyou so much can i please contact you if i get another issue?

Comment: How would i extract data from the page i want would i use 
 Elements ticketNumber = doc.select("body > div.MainBox.ARIARoleMain.UseArticleColors > div.Headline > h1");
   
or a get request?